# parse-server js can't login user, even though registration goes through and logs user in

Tags: javascript, vue.js, parse-server

I'm currently building a parse-server app with vuejs + vuex on the front end.

I am able to register an account(and once registered the user is logged in) with this code:

```
REGISTER_USER (state, username, email, password) {
var user = new Parse.User()
user.set('username', username)
user.set('password', password)
user.set('email', email)
user.signUp(null, {
  success: function (user) {
    state.currentUser = user
  },
  error: function (user, error) {
    state.registerError = error
  }
})
}
```

but if I log the user out and try to log them in with:

```
LOGIN_USER (state, email, password) {
Parse.User.logIn(email, password, {
  success: function (user) {
    state.currentUser = user
  },
  error: function (user, error) {
    state.loginError = error
    console.log('error logging in: ' + JSON.stringify(error) + ' userobject: ' + JSON.stringify(user))
    console.log('current user: ' + JSON.stringify(Parse.User.current()))
  }
})
}
```

I get `{"code":101,"error":"Invalid username/password."}`

I've confirmed that the proper username and password is reaching the function, but then it goes south somehow. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: According to documentation, [mutations](http://vuejs.github.io/vuex/en/mutations.html) must be Synchronous and actions should be asynchronous. So the code inside those mutations should be in your actions, anyway, I'm not sure if thats your particular problem

Comment: you might be correct, although vuex is watching for changed values within the store which so far seem to work ok. but I agree, I don't think that is why this particular issue is occurring.

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured it out. There are 2 available methods for login, tried the other one and worked perfectly

https://parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.User.html#methods_logIn

```
var user = new Parse.User()
user.set('username', username)
user.set('password', password)

user.logIn({
success: function (user) {
  this.username = ''
  this.password = ''
  dispatch('SET_CURRENT_USER', user)
},
  error: function (user, error) {
    // console.log('login errors: ' + JSON.stringify(error) + 'for user: ' + JSON.stringify(user))
    // state.loginErrors = error
  }
})
```